# How to make an object type / interface based on an array of strings

Tags: typescript

I am getting some JSON objects from a network call, of the shape:

```
{
  timestamp: "1636814680595",
  price: "$1",
  ...manyOtherKeys
}
```

All values are strings.

I'd like to create an interface based on an array of the expected keys. From this:

```
const expectedKeys = ['timestamp', 'price', ...]
```

I would like to programmatically generate the type (or interface):

```
type ExpectedType {
  timestamp: string, 
  price: string
}
```

Is there an easy way to do that? For now, all I can think of is the following, which seems contrived:

```
// I did not find a way to start from an array and reduce it to this object
// while preserving the type. I'm okay starting with this object instead of
// an array of string. 
const objectWithExpectedShape = {
  timestamp: '',
  price: '',
}
type ExpectedType = typeof objectWithExpectedShape;
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but something that might help is the io-ts library. https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts. I currently use this to validate data coming from the client (from JSON, like your example) to coerce them into real domain models that conform to a strict interface. This could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is only possible if the `expectedKeys` is static - if you hard-code it. (If they're dynamically generated and not present in the source code, it's impossible, because TypeScript types only operate on what exists at compile-time - at runtime, you're only left with plain JavaScript)

Define the array `as const` so it doesn't get widened to `string[]`, and then you can make a Record composed of the keys (the array items) and `string`.

```
const expectedKeys = ['timestamp', 'price'] as const;
type ExpectedType = Record<
    typeof expectedKeys[number],
    string
>;
```